# merge two sorted list of items in python

Tags: python, merge

My question has to do with figuring out different ways to merge 2 sorted items? 
I try to find an easy way to merge 2 sorted items.

```
def merge(arr1, arr2):
    return sorted(arr1 + arr2)

# Example: merge([1, 4, 7], [2, 3, 6, 9]) => [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9]
```

I'm not sure if I'm complicating it. This uses [a built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#sorted), meaning it's harder to mess up the implementation details.

I also find that I can use the merge() function from [cypthon's heapq](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/heapq.py#L314).

Wondering if there's any thought of using other method likee the following:

[Gist for Merge in python](https://gist.github.com/Jeffchiucp/9dc2a5108429c4222fe4b2a25e35c778)

Comment: What is the question?  What are you trying to do? Why is it wrong?

Comment: sorted(arr1+arr2) as you wrote is already sufficient. You can compare the timings of different methods suggested in the answers for very large lists and see what’s best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its up to you which implementation you use. The consideration is whether you need a clean code or you need performance.

For clean code you can use:

1. sorted(l1+l2)
2. merge from heappq

both of this with complexity O(nlogn)

whereas this implementation is https://gist.github.com/Jeffchiucp/9dc2a5108429c4222fe4b2a25e35c778 with algorithm complexity O(n).

Answer (score 1):

use [merge](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) from heapq

```
>>> l1 = [1, 4, 7]
>>> l2 = [2, 3, 6, 9]
>>> from heapq import merge
>>> list(merge(l1,l2))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to concatenate two sorted lists and sort them again, it's not needed. There are `O(n)` algorithms for merging sorted lists, your algorithm would be `O(n log n)` because of sorting again.  Merging two sorted lists using `Priority queue` taken from [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/discuss/10511/10-line-python-solution-with-priority-queue):

```
from Queue import PriorityQueue
class Solution(object):
    def mergeKLists(self, lists):
        dummy = ListNode(None)
        curr = dummy
        q = PriorityQueue()
        for node in lists:
            if node: q.put((node.val,node))
        while q.qsize()>0:
            curr.next = q.get()[1]
            curr=curr.next
            if curr.next: q.put((curr.next.val, curr.next))
        return dummy.next
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
def merge_sorted_list(list1,list2):
  i = j = 0
  while(i < len(list1) and j < len(list2)):
    if(list1[i] > list2[j]):
      list1.insert(i, list2[j])
      i+=1
      j+=1
    else:
      i+=1
  if(j < len(list2)):
    list1.extend(list2[j:])
  return list1

print(merge_sorted_list([1, 4, 7],[2, 3, 6, 9]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def cleanMerge(self, list1, list2):
    if len(list1)!=len(list2):
        less = list1 if len(list1)<len(list2) else list2
        chosenList = list2 if len(list1)<len(list2) else list1
    chosenList = list1
    less = list2
    l1,l2,r1,r2 = 0,0,len(chosenList),len(less)
    while l2<r2 and l1<r1:
        if chosenList[l1]>less[l2]:
            chosenList[l1+1:r1+1] = chosenList[l1:r1]
            chosenList[l1] = less[l2]
            l2+=1
            l1+=1
            r1+=1
        else:
            l1+=1
            continue
    if l2<r2:
        for item in less[l2:r2]:
            chosenList.append(item)
    return chosenList
```